# Uninstalled office version asks for activation

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010, license

I have a computer that had Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 trial installed. The trial was supposed to end in two days, so I purchased a Microsoft Office Professional 2010 license (don't ask my why I didn't purchase an Office Professional Plus license, I'm not the one who bought the license).

I've followed this Microsoft KB: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg534648.aspx; and used the uninstall-install option.

The whole process was successful, Office Professional Plus was uninstalled and Office Professional was installed.

Now when I run Word or Outlook, I still get the pop-up window from Office Professional Plus notifying me that the trial period will end in two days and that I have to activate the product. When I go to the help menu, here's what I see:

[image]

It seems that the old Office Professional Plus version is still somewhere, but I can't find it and remove it completely.

I've googled for 2 hours and I couldn't find a similar case to mine.

I've looked into the registry and I found two registration keys, one that had the old name of the computer and one that had the new name of the computer. I figured that the one with the old name was linked to Office Professional Plus, so I exported it and then deleted it.
It didn't solve the problem, even after restarting the machine.

Can anyone help out on this?? Thank you very much.

Comment: I would contact Microsoft Support for assistance.

Comment: it sounds like registry problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a complete uninstall of all Office 2010 products first.

I would then attempt removing the registry keys pertaining to the activation of Office 2010. If you have 32-bit Windows, then there will only be **first** of the following keys. In 64-bit Windows, both are there:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0
```

I remove the entire `/14.0` registry key in both locations to completely remove activation. After that, install again. Activation may or may not require you to do an over-the-phone activation, which takes all of 5 minutes.